# HTML Section Paging

Tags: html

How can I link my header href menu into a page of section with the header still on the top in my inner html.

Here is the header and div menu:

```
        <img src="img/logo.png" width="65" height="65">
    <h1 style="color:#B2BCB1;">Bangkit<small>WM</small></h1>

    <div id="menu">

    <a href="#">About</a>

    <a href="#">Portofolio</a>

    <a href="#">Contact</a>

    </div>

</header>
```

And here is the section class that i want to linked in href of header menu:

```
<div class="main">  
    <section class="page one">
        <div class="page-container">
            <h2>About Me</h2>
            <p>Fokus untuk mengakhiri karir</p>
            <p><small><a href="bangkitwira.com"></a><a href="index2.html">That was a Child</a></small></p>
        </div>
    </section>



    <section class="page two">
        <div class="page-container">
            <h2>Portofolio</h2>
            <p>Menerangkan pekerjaan web yang sudahberhasil saya buat</p>
        </div>
    </section>



    <Section class="page three">
        <div class="page-container">
            <h2>Contact<small> &bull; Me</small></h2>
            <p>Mengapa? Karena untuk memudahkan komunikasi diantara kita</p>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ids on elements as well as classes.

This link:

```
<a href="#page_one">About</a>
```

Will send the user to this `div`:

```
<section id="page_one" class="page one">
    <div class="page-container">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <p>Fokus untuk mengakhiri karir</p>
        <p><small><a href="bangkitwira.com"></a><a href="index2.html">That was a Child</a></small></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

As an aside this declaration:

```
<section class="page three">
```

Will give the section 2 classes, not one. An element can have multiple classes if they are separated by a space.

Comment: i have already try a kind like that, but the header is dissapear

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I whipped up to give you an idea of what you want to achieve:

**The CSS:**

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
}
section:before {
    display: block;
    content:" ";
    margin-top: -100px;
    height: 100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.main {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

This is necessary to make your header stick to the top, and to prevent overlapping issues. Adjust '100px' to something around '165px' if it doesn't look nice (I removed the image tag from my test code).

**The HTML:**

Change your HTML to give your `section`s IDs and to make your hyperlinks point towards those IDs.

Note to also add the class `sticky` to your header.

```
<section id="sectionOne" class="page one">
<!-- more code here -->
<a href="#sectionOne">About</a>
```

Behold!

Comment: I use the onepagescroll jquery, i have change but the header still dissapear

Comment: You really should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: now the header i have changed the position into fixed, the header appear, but the header covered the section

Comment: Did you implement the rest of the CSS? If that fails, replace all instances of `100px` to something greater. Like `200px`.

Comment: You should also apply the same properties in the `.sticky` class to your header.

Comment: which css that you mean, is that the main?

Comment: i've change the header properties, the header was shown, but the page was broken

Comment: when i clicked on section one, the section page one covered by the header

Comment: Can you create a JSFIDDLE with your code and link to it here? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/JtshY/, i've write the css and the javascript